# Display feature info as tooltips

Tags: geojson, popup, geoext, ext-js

I load a map with data and collect information in a JSON file.  I want a tooltip appear when mousing over a town on the map.

```
   var vecLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector", {
        styleMap: styleMap,
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            // url: "app/data/summits.json",
            //url: "app/data/chargeIndicateur.php",
            url: "../web/app_dev.php/json/indicateur/"+gIndicateur+"/"+gEchelle+"/"+gPeriode,
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON(),
            idProperty: 'Issam'

        }),

, {
// dock: 'right',
xtype: 'toolbar',
id    : 'teste2',

items: [{
text: 'Nom',
labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;',
}]
} ,
```

Comment: my email can be find in my user profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see **[here](http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/files/ol3.html)** a tooltip showing different properties from a GeoJSON file. Also, reading **[this](http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/olvectors.html)** article will help you to adapt your code to your needs.